# how in php to make the format of the figures French

Tags: php, format

tell me please how the figure for example 1222333,00 make the format thus 1 222 333.00 in php

```
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td align=center>";
    echo $rs->Fields(1)->Name();
   echo "</td>";
   echo "<td align=center>";
   echo round(($rs->Fields(1)->value*1),3)."<br />";
   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: how do I put the format in the code $nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');

Comment: Try $nombre_format_francais = number_format($number,2,"."," ");

Comment: @KarloKokkak Please do not link to external sites that might died in the future. Better provide short and working example here to keep it as a reference for other users reading this post in the future

Comment: Ok. Got it.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **number_format();** - for French notation of the value

Updated your code:

```
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td align=center>";
   echo $rs->Fields(1)->Name();
   echo "</td>";
   echo "<td align=center>";
   echo number_format(($rs->Fields(1)->value*1), 2, ',', ' ')."<br />";
   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert format of any number use PHP native function [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) .

```
$number = '1222333,00';

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');

echo $nombre_format_francais; // 1 222 333,00
```

**Live demo: https://eval.in/974301**

Comment: thanks for your comments but how do I include in my code
'$ nombre_format_francais = number_format ($ number, 2, ',', '');'